# How to dynamically highlight the minimum value in Excel or OpenOffice.org Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, openoffice, microsoft-works

I am using Microsoft spreadsheet to record the numeric values in columns.
I would like to compute the minimum of the row and want to highlight it when the cursor moves to next row.

Could you kindly suggest alternatives to do this ?

Edit 2 :

***If this possible in Excel or OpenOffice.org Calc?***

Comment: Just to clarify, which are you *actually* using- Works Spreadsheet or Excel?

Comment: works spreadsheet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To highlight it right away (without actually moving to the next row), use conditional formatting, like:

> Cell value is less than or equal to `MIN($A1:$ZZ1)`

In OpenOffice.org:

[image: Result in OpenOffice.org]